# Keep only the latest document per id in Solr after loading core

Tags: solr, lucene

I have documents like the following:

```
{
  id: X
  pos: y
  fields....
}
```

My unique key is the "id" field and "pos" is a counter which goes up for each loaded document.
For performance reasons I want to load the core ASAP and avoid deletion during loading (using overwrite=true cause degradation of 33% in indexing throughput).
Is there an easy way I can ask Solr after completing loading the core to remove all documents with the same "id" field while leaving only the ones with the latest "pos" field (in each unique "id" group)?
If there are better techniques to boost loading without dealing with deletes, I'll be happy to learn about.
If I need to delete them manually, I'm looking for a query that in case of the following docs:

```
{id:1 pos:0}
{id:1 pos:1}
{id:1 pos:2}
{id:2 pos:3}
{id:2 pos:4}
```

will return:

```
{id:1 pos:0}
{id:1 pos:1}
{id:2 pos:3}
```

So I can delete them.

Comment: How are you indexing? Duplication removal might be more efficient before hitting Solr. You'll probably have to implement a custom deletion script after indexing has completed to get what you're asking otherwise.

Comment: I'm indexing with solrj client. Removing duplicate before indexing isn't possible but I do know when I'm encountering an update if it helps. @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to do delete in such a grouped fashion. However, a query to identify duplicate documents with position less than maximum is possible.

I would use either [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) or [Result Collapsing/Expanding](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results).

With **Result Grouping**, the query params would look something like:

```
"q":"*:*"
"group":"true"
"group.field":"id",
"group.sort":"pos desc"
"group.limit":"1000"
"group.offset":"1"
```

Sort and offset combine to exclude the top (highest **pos**) document for each value of **id**. This assumes **pos** field is indexed as numerics of some sort.

With **collapsing/expanding**, the query parameters could be instead:

```
"q": "*:*"
"fq": "{!collapse field=id max=pos}"
"expand": "true"
```

This puts the top **pos** documents for each **id** in the main results body and all the documents to delete in the **expanded** section. Just notice that the expanded section will only include the documents for ids that appear in the main results sections. So, you need large enough row count or proper paging to get all the results.